# AngularJS unbind directive without destroying scope

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to unbind all the values from a directive template.

I usually do that via scope.$destroy but this particular time i can't destroy the scope because it inherits the parent one and i need it elsewhere.

I can't either bind once because it needs to be updated.

Is it possible somehow to totally unbind the template (ie, make it static) of a directive without destroying its scope?

TIA

Comment: Please make an example. I don't understand if you want to freeze the object at some time. You could duplicate the model having in the template bind to your internal copy of the model.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i want to achieve. Basically the problem is that i have some sort of animation AFTER i set some value on the scope, during which i'd like to keep the old data in the directive (for mere graphical purposes).

Comment: I actually thought about duplicating the model and then destroy the child scope, but as it's more than one value i thought there might be an easiest way to 'staticize' the dom element..

Answer (score 0):

A good solution could be to call [Object.freeze(scope.model)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) on your directive

Comment: My directive has no scope, i would freeze my parent object.Which i don't want to.

Comment: so duplicate the object with angular.extend({}, scope.model) and watch for changes on the duplicate. if then freeze your object when you want to. It is possible to deregister a watch after is no longer needed. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2480-unbinding-watch-listeners-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: Wouldn't angular extend just create a copy of it? The 'parent' object will be changed and the copy won't..

Comment: yes, that's because you may need a watch on this model to change the original model when you think is good. Then it is possible to unbind the watch when you freeze your object.